# How to make slider that changes operator properties

Tags: python, operator

I have a custom operator called `collection.vary_collection` that has an `IntProperty` called `color_step`. I managed to create a UI button calling the operator and I would like to add a slider that changes that property but I don't know what is the proper way to do that. So far I have just a slider but it doesn't respond :

[image]

This is my draw function :

```
def draw(self, context):
    props= self.layout.operator(
        'collection.vary_collection',
        text= 'Make Variants',
        icon= 'OUTLINER_OB_GROUP_INSTANCE'
    );
    self.layout.prop(props, 'color_step');
```

Can anyone help me with that or at least link me to some similar working examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operators usually have their properties available in Adjust Last operator panel (F9) so if an operator has some property and has 'REGISTER' and 'UNDO' options:

[image]

it will show up in the panel after being used:

[image]

That's sort of standard way of doing things in Blender, but if you needed to have some property set before the operator is executed, you need to store it somewhere. If I understand it correctly, one common way to store global properties is in WindowManager:

```
import bpy

bpy.types.WindowManager.int_p = bpy.props.IntProperty(name = "Some Name", default=15)

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"
    
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.window_manager, "int_p")
        row.operator("mesh.primitive_cylinder_add").vertices = context.window_manager.int_p

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

And [here is the link with all the parameters available for integer properties](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.IntProperty)

Comment: Thank you. My operator has already an UNDO support and all it was missing was that option to set the parameters before execution. Thank you so much!